# Как вернуть консоль Windows в CLion 2018.2.3

Tags: c++, clion

После перехода с 2017 версии на 2018 во время debug программа запускается в режиме встроенной консоли, кроме того если в программе возникнет `SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)` то при запуске дебагинга она сразу вылетает (прекращена работа программы) затем нужно нажать отладка, отмена и только тогда запустится пошаговый дебагинг который был раньше.
Можно ли как-то вернуть старую консоль?
Как пошагово выполнить программу до ее вылета?
`Shift + F9` запускают дебаг уже в новом режиме
`File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console -> Always show debug console`  тоже не помогает
CLion 2018.2.3, MinGW 5.0, CMake 3.9.4

Comment: На сайте разработчиков вычитал что они наконец то  сделали встроенную консоль для всех платформ потому что из под винды она работала криво(встроенная до сих пор работает криво). Зато работающую консоль виндовс они убрали. Временно решил откатив версию назад